# OpenAuth - Firebase versus GoogleAPI

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I am building an Android Application and have to choose as my primary means of authenticating the user. If GoogleID is my only preferred choice of authenticating/signing-on a user, then should I use Firebase or just Google Auth directly?

Would I get any performance benefit if I use Firebase instead of Google?
What are the other benefits of using Firebase instead of Google API directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use Firebase Auth because aside from Firebase's well-written documentation, it makes it easy for you to use Facebook Login, Twitter Login, Github Login and the conventional email login. Also, Firebase was made with "mobile-first" in mind.

Checkout [Introducing Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/06/introducing-firebase-authentication.html) as well:

> With [Firebase
>   Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/?utm_campaign=Firebase_featureoverview_education_auth_en_06-22-16&utm_source=Firebase&utm_medium=blog),
>   you can outsource your entire authentication system to Firebase so
>   that you can concentrate on building great features for your app.
>   Firebase Authentication makes it easier to get your users signed-in
>   without having to understand the complexities behind implementing your
>   own authentication system. It offers a straightforward getting started
>   experience, optional UX components designed to minimize user friction,
>   and is built on open standards and backed by Google infrastructure.